# How to do HTML layout for rows of complex records?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to display a list of complex records and trying to simply fit it into a table doesn't seem to be working very well.

I'd like a layout that goes something like this:

[image: mockup]

Each whole record could be put into a table cell (one cell per row), and then I could use `<div>` tags within each cell. Is putting divs into table cells likely to cause display problems? It could be simply done with divs anyway, so perhaps that's a bad idea.

Within each record, there are quite a number of components. If I lay these out with divs, what do I need to do to ensure each label/value pair is in the right position? Or is there some better way to ensure a consistent layout?

Obviously the values for each record will be different so to maintain a consistent look I would need the labels to all line up vertically.

If the question seems a bit vague, then it's because my understanding of how to do it is vague... even some help clarifying the question would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at HTML 5, the [article tag](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) might fit here. The fact that you have an "Author Element" seems to make it a good fit. If you are not looking at HTML 5 just use a `div` instead of `article`. Or as @Moin Zaman mentioned use `ul` and use `li` in place of `article` in my example below.

As for ensuring your labels etc line up vertically this is fairly easy to achieve. Just explicitly set the widths via css.

Here is a quick example:

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <h2>ID: 123</h2>
    <div class="actions">
        <input type="button" value="Do Someting" />  
        <input type="button" value="Do Someting Else" />  
        <input type="button" value="And Maybe something Else" />  
    </div>
    <div class="description">A fairly long description that takes up basically the entire width of the section, maybe even longer still</div>
    <div class="details">
        <div class="author"><span>Author:</span>Douglas Adams</div>
        <div class="created"><span>Created:</span>1 Jan 2012</div>
        <div class="label first"><span>Label 1:</span>Value</div>
        <div class="label"><span>Label 2:</span>Value</div>
        <div class="label"><span>Label 3:</span>Value</div>
        <div style="clear:both; line-height:0px;">&nbsp;</div><!-- Use A Clear Fix Instead of this, I got Lazy!! -->
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article
{
    border: solid 2px black;
    margin:20px;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
}

article h2
{
    background:#FFF;
    padding:5px 8px;
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
    left:5px;
    display:inline;
}

article .actions
{
    float:right;
    width:25%;
    text-align:right;    
    position:relative;
}

article .actions input
{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    clear:both;
}

article .details
{
    position:releative;
    width:70%;
}

.author
{
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}

.created
{
    float:left;
    width:40%
}

.label
{
    float:left;
    width:30%;    
}    


.label span, .author span, .created span
{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:3px;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2fAx/2/)

**Note:** Use a [clear fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) instead of having the clearing div.

Answer (score 2):

Using divs in table cells is fine. Shouldn't cause issues.

Although looking at your mockup, semantically I would say its not a table. No columns, column headings etc.

It looks more like a list of items with more details in them.

I'd use a ul with li's and divs inside to lay things out further.

Also if you need the ID sitting exactly like that you could use a legend element inside each li.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="label">ID 345</span>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="desc" colspan="3">A fairly long description that takes up basically the entire width of the section, maybe even longer still</td>
    <td rowspan="3" class="doStuff">Do Something<br />Do another thing<br />Maybe 1 more thing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="author"colspan="2"><span>Author: </span>Joe Bloggs</td>
    <td class="created"><span>Created: </span>19th June 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label3"><span>Label 3: </span>Value</td>
    <td class="label4"><span>Label 4: </span>Value</td>
    <td class="label5"><span>Label 5: </span>Value</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
div{
    margin:17px 10px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
span.label{
    background:#FFF;
    padding:5px 8px;
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    left:5px;
}
table{
    width:100%;
}
tr{
    background:#ccc;
}
td{
    padding:5px 7px;
}
span{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

[jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/QActK/](http://jsfiddle.net/QActK/)

Comment: I don't think that table is the right element here from a semantic point of view. That and you are using a table for layout purposes which is really frowned upon these days

Comment: I quite agree, divs would be a much better solution. This is just how one would likely do it if tables were used. Looks like Jon P has a good div/span solution already posted.